# HTML Select without dropdown list for mobile website

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm developing a mobile website for an online apparel website.  For the size or color dropdown lists, I want to list options side by side and let users touch the option they want instead of using dropdown lists.  This is how it is used in many mobile websites including m.macys.com and m.shopbop.com.  I was just curious how to do this with html and javascript.

Thank you.

Seong

Comment: Just create each option as a separate ``<div>``, register a click/touch handler on them and when the user clicks one, add some CSS style that will make it highlighted in some way (and remove that style from all the other options). You can do it easily using pure JavaScript or any JS library, like jQuery.

Comment: Why not just use a radio `input`?

Answer (score 0):

You might be better off using a Javascript library that is specifically designed for mobile web development, e.g. [jQuery Mobile](http://jquerymobile.com/) (check out the [demos](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/)), [JQTouch](http://jqtouch.com/), [XUI](http://xuijs.com/) (also see the *Alternative* section at the bottom of their page).